# SOAP UI Assertion Help : To validate Total attribute and Total Value

Tags: json, groovy, automated-tests, soapui, assertions

I searched in Google and Stackoverflow and I didn't find any helpful information and decide to post question.

I am getting response from API in JSON.

```
{
"CouponCode": [{
    "id": 56,
    "name": "BlackFriday"
}, {
    "id": 58,
    "name": "ThanksGiving"
}, {
    "id": 62,
    "name": "New Year"
}]}
```

I need to add assertion that will count that there are total 3 id and 3 name.

All IDs and Names are not empty. We don't want to send empty attribute value.

I am using SOAP UI open source. Please provide exact code or exact reference.

Exactly assertion needs to

- Find total Ids and Name that's will be size
- Find total Ids and Name size.

If Id is 3 and 3 Ids value are three..if JSON come like in this case assertion will failed.

this

```
{
"CouponCode": [{
    "id": 56,
    "name": "BlackFriday"
}, {
    "id": 58,
    "name": "ThanksGiving"
}, {
    "id": "",
    "name": "New Year"
}]}
```

Comment: using answered question. I compare both dynamic count value and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below `groovy script` uses `json` way to check the expected results.

Add the `groovy script` step after the `rest request` step in your test case.

Sudo code for extracting the same.

1. Read the `json` text. If you do not want to use fixed response, read it from previous step response. Create the object.
2. Make sure you have the expected counts for id, and name. You may also define them at test case custom properties in case do not want to use fixed values and change each time in the script.
3. find all the `id` count and check with expected value and show the error message in case of failure.
4. Similar to step 3, do the assert for names.

```groovy
//for testing using fixed response, you may aslo assign dynamic response.
def jsonText = '''
{
"CouponCode": [{
    "id": 56,
    "name": "BlackFriday"
}, {
    "id": 58,
    "name": "ThanksGiving"
}, {
    "id": 62,
    "name": "New Year"
}]}'''

def coupons =  new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonText).CouponCode
//You may also read these values from test case properties
def expectedIdCount = 3
def expectedNameCount = 3
//assert the expected id count with find all coupon ids count of json response
assert expectedIdCount == coupons.findAll{it.id}.size(), "Coupon id count does not match"
//assert the expected name count with find all coupon names count of json response
assert expectedNameCount == coupons.findAll{it.name}.size(), "Coupon name count does not match"
```

The same can be achieved using `script assertion` for the rest step as well, that will avoid additional groovy script step. But it may require little changes in the script as below.

*How to read the `json` response dynamically?*

**From script assertion** 

Use below line and remove the fixed jsonText from above.
`def jsonText = messageExchange.response.responseContent`

**From Groovy script step**
//replace the rest request step name below
 `def jsonText = context.expand('${ReplaceStepName#Response}')`

*How to read the test case level properties for expected results instead of hardcoded values in the script?*

Define a test case level property for `id`, say `EXPECTED_ID_COUNT` and provide value 3 like you mentioned and similarly, define for `name` as well.

`//read in script these properties`

`def expectedIdCount = context.testCase.getPropertyValue('EXPECTED_ID_COUNT') as Integer`

Comment: Rao - What is It ? Here assert expectedIdCount == coupons.findAll{it.id}.size()

Comment: Added comment, please check. There is also sudo code mentioned in the beginning.

Comment: I update my question. i think I was not clear. We are very close

Comment: Ok, did you try the script provided? What happened?

Comment: You case gets handled as well, showing error `Coupon id count does not match. Expression: (expectedIdCount == coupons.findAll({ -> ... }).size()). Values: expectedIdCount = 3`

Comment: def expectedIdCount = 3
def expectedNameCount = 3 this need to find value of name and Id count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105177/discussion-between-rao-and-boston-star).

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible [solutions](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html). The easiest is to use an XPath assertion; keep in mind that internally, SoapUI converts everything to XML if it can.

```
count(//*:id)
```

expected result:

```
3
```

Similarly for your `name`.

Comment: How I can write assertion of both ..like count(//*:id) = id value ?

Comment: @BostonStar I don't understand your question. The XPath assertion has two windows: XPath statement, and Expected value.

Comment: There is other window called "script assertion" under script